# RestSharp execute sync, not async

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, restsharp

Is there a way to use restsharp synchronously? Every method I see in Visual Studio has the "async" postfix and the restsharp main page, (which has the following example):

```
// execute the request
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
```

Clearly makes the distinction between sync and async requests:

```
// easy async support
client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
});
```

How can I access this "Execute" sync method?

Comment: I installed Restsharp and can't access the "Execute" method, any ideas?

Comment: Check this https://restsharp.dev/v107/ 
"...All the synchronous methods are gone. If you absolutely must call without using async and await, use GetAwaiter().GetResult() blocking call..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked in their googlegroups and they said that it is because of "platorm limitations" when using wp7. Pretty neat right?

Comment: Async is the best way to do it in any case. They don't provide sync methods because they don't want people building unresponsive apps.

Comment: I think it's probably better to be nesting callback after callback.

Comment: Check this https://restsharp.dev/v107/ "...All the synchronous methods are gone. If you absolutely must call without using async and await, use GetAwaiter().GetResult() blocking call..."